# Programmatically Fix text into viewBox

Tags: svg

I have this svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 ' + size + ' ' + size +'" width="'+ boxW +'" height="'+ boxH +'">
  <text>Sample Text</text>
</svg>
```

`size`: A parameter that is needed to the viewBox in order to create the wrapper.

`width` & `height`: the width and height of the container of the text.

I have a function that generate this svg. The problem is that the text is not fitting into the box; the result is like this:

[image]

(Is blue due to the Chrome inspector, you can see up in the top-left corner the text being small instead of full size.

The SVG resulted is this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1"
     viewBox="0 0 580 532">
  <text x="0" y="15" style="font-family:Arial;fill:%230000ff;fill-opacity:1;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;"
     >test</text>
</svg>
```

The whole img is this:

```
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,&lt;svg xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2000/svg&quot; version=&quot;1.1&quot; viewBox=&quot;0 0 580 532&quot;&gt;&lt;text x=&quot;0&quot; y=&quot;15&quot; style=&quot;font-family:Arial;fill:%230000ff;fill-opacity:1;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;&quot;&gt;test&lt;/text&gt;&lt;/svg&gt;" class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" alt="" tabindex="0" style="margin-left: -298px; margin-top: -291px; width: 309px; height: 295px; transform: translate3d(683px, 317px, 0px); z-index: 317; outline: none;">
```

So my quesiton is: How to fit the text into the main wrapper?

Comment: Your sample code at the top, doesn't match any of the sample outputs you list later in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You either have to:

1. fit the `viewBox` to the text, or
2. fit the text to the `viewBox`.

You are not doing either.  You are not even setting a `font-size`.

Option 1 is not really available to you. You can measure the text if you have access to the SVG DOM, but you can't do that if you aren't in a rendering environment, like a browser.

Perhaps you could use a font loading library to get metadata about the glyphs in the font. Then calculate the size of a piece of text that way.  You don't mention which language you are using to produce these SVGs, so I can't advise further on that.

So you are left with option 2.  The only option that SVG has to let you fit text to a particular size, is the `textLength` and `lengthAdjust` attributes on the `<text>` element.

- `textLength`

  Sets a length to which you want the text to be fitted
- `lengthAdjust`

  Sets the method to be used to adjust the length. You can either stretch just the spacing between the letters, or you can stretch the letter glyphs

See [the `<text>` section in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#text-TextElement) for more information

There are no options for adjusting the text height.

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 40">
  <line x1="10" y1="30" x2="190" y2="30" stroke="black" opacity="0.2"/>
  <text x="10" y="30"
        textLength="180"
        lengthAdjust="spacing">Sample Text</text>
</svg>

<br/>

<svg viewBox="0 0 200 40">
  <line x1="10" y1="30" x2="190" y2="30" stroke="black" opacity="0.2"/>
  <text x="10" y="30"
        textLength="180"
        lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">Sample Text</text>
</svg>
```

If you want the font size to be a better match, then you are going to have to work out a method of calculating an approximate font size.  Eg.

```
var  numChars = text.length()
var  fontSize = (desiredTextWidth / numChars) * someScalingFactor
```

The scaling factor will depend on your font.

Comment: Thanks. This kinda solved my problem. Sad fact is that the height of the text is now working properly. https://imgur.com/a/R7CIEli The green text is "456", but stretched like this way

Comment: Sad how?  How were you expecting to fit the short string like "456" into such a wide length. What did you want the text to look like?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution: I'm putting the text inside a `<symbol>`. I get the size of the text with `getBBox()` and use it to set the `viewBox` for the `<symbol>`. Please note that the `<use>` element has a width of 100%.

```js
let bb = text.getBBox();
test.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `${bb.x} ${bb.y} ${bb.width} ${bb.height}`);
```

```css
*{font-size:16px;}
svg{border:1px solid;width:90vh}
body{font-family:Arial;fill:#0000ff;fill-opacity:1;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
```

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 580 532">
<symbol id="test">

<text id="text" dominant-baseline="central" text-anchor="middle" >test</text>
</symbol>   
<use id="_use" xlink:href="#test" width="100%" />
</svg>
```